# Typescript generics loop over object array and intersect them

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Say there's a function `X` which takes any number of objects:

```
export function X<T extends object[]>(...classes: T): MergedClasses<T>;
```

I would like it to return the intersection of every object in that list.
For instance, given objects `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` it would go something like:

```
let X = A & B
X = X & C
X = X & D
// for any number of objects
```

However, I would like to do this as a type for the return type of the function (hence `MergedClasses`)

```
type MergedClasses<C extends object[]> = {
}
```

I know it's possible to do `[K for keyof C]:`  but from there I'm not sure how I could combine the objects, since there is no way to assign variables.

I checked out Lodash's [merge typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/1fa1f387c466efb5f208d766d970168826a793e1/types/lodash/v3/index.d.ts#L13772) and it is just an overloaded function that takes 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 objects. So it *seems* like it can merge any number of objects, but it can't actually do more than 5.

Is it possible to dynamically merge the objects, or will I have to take the same route as Lodash did?

Comment: Each parameter needs an explicit generic type, so you'll need to go with the Lodash route

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution using a recursive definition:

```
type IntersectionOf<A extends any[]> = A extends [infer T, ...infer R] ? T & IntersectionOf<R> : unknown

// type Test = {a: string} & {b: number} & {c: boolean}
type Test = IntersectionOf<[{a: string}, {b: number}, {c: boolean}]>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdsCAnAzhAxsAlgezgeQDMAeAQSggA9E4ATFKAQzhAG0BdAPigF4pyqNelFZY4hZFAAqAGigA6RWIlIoAJXZQA-NKgAyWAmRpMuAiTXcAXFACucANZwcAdzgAodwHovUUJGkIFGBeKABvRhtgpDEAcwBffXCAIxs4WwBbZOREgzD0G2ScHAAbCGZ4939oKSCQvnhEVAxsPCJiVgio4Bi4BLkw1Kh0rJyBgqgi0vK4eK53IA)

Here's an alternative, slightly messier solution using the `UnionToIntersection` helper from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/12299000), which might be preferable if the first solution runs up against the compiler's recursion limit. However, note that this will have incorrect behaviour if any of the input types is a union, since those will be converted to intersections too.

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never
type IntersectionOf<A extends any[]> = UnionToIntersection<A[number]>

// type Test = {a: string} & {b: number} & {c: boolean}
type Test = IntersectionOf<[{a: string}, {b: number}, {c: boolean}]>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIJJ2BATgZwgGNhk4AeGAPigF4oAKGKCADxzgBN8oBDOEFAD8jANYAuWAEo6NAG5IEnKJLgQ5eGWw7dGDCVARwAZnigYZteYs4yRGFVDUbcAKFCRz2PIRJkA8sbkAIIs7BBcPPwgANoAujT08GToWDgExKQoITFwAK4AtgBGeAmurgD0FVAe0KgQ+MB0UADevJKNuEYA5gC+UABkrUWqhSW4-UMtRJJFSEgANhD8ve7gdQ1N9Gk+mQFBMW0dwF1wfQA0w6PFeL2X07PzSytlQA)